# How to automate creating multi-tenants schema?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, oauth

I am working on a project using Java, Spring, and PostgreSQL that will have multiple stores and each store will be separate from each other having each their own products. I am kind of new to multi-tenancy database. Each store will have its own separate users with specific roles which will be lower than who will manage all the stores. User will login with their own credential generating an authentication token that I can use to identify them with and create a new store for the user registered as a merchant. What way I should go with? or What framework I should use that can help me separate stores from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [CUBA Platform](https://www.cuba-platform.com/framework/) based on Spring framework.

[CUBA Platform Guides](https://www.cuba-platform.com/guides/): [Introduction to Working with Data](https://www.cuba-platform.com/guides/intro-working-with-data-in-cuba)

> CUBA compiles mainstream JVM technologies into a powerful environment, responding to modern development standards and common requirements of business applications.

## Multitenancy addon for CUBA platform

There is open-source production-tested [Multitenancy addon](https://www.cuba-platform.com/marketplace/multitenancy/) for CUBA platform:

> The add-on implements a single database multitenancy support for CUBA applications.
>   It enables using a single application instance to serve multiple tenants — groups of users that are invisible to each other and do not share any data they have write access to.
>
> The component supports two types of data:
>   -   Common data — shared across tenants.
>   -   Tenant-specific data — not accessible to other tenants.
>
> All tenants have their own admin users which can create tenant users and assign tenant-specific roles and permissions.
>
> ### Features
>
> - Access differentiation to data for groups of users within a single application.
> - Simple configuring of tenant-specific entities.
> - User interface for managing tenants.
>
> ### Links
>
> - [Demo project](https://github.com/cuba-platform/multitenancy-addon-demo)
> - [Documentation](https://github.com/cuba-platform/multitenancy-addon/blob/master/README.md)

[multitenancy-addon on GitHub](https://github.com/cuba-platform/multitenancy-addon)

Disclaimer: I work for haulmont.com

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @0x01Brain welcome to ask any questions. There is also [community forum](https://www.cuba-platform.com/discuss/)

Comment: Look at this article https://medium.com/deviniti-technology-driven-blog/how-to-automate-your-multi-tenant-architecture-b87faf67898